# Add folder to gitignore if it was previously commited

Tags: git

I have merged my whole project on master branch.

After few commits with pushes, I have realized that I need to ignore directory from my commits.

I have added

```
database/
```

to my .gitignore file, but when I try again to commit and create pull request this folder normally exists in my commit.

How can I add it trully to .gitignore, after these several pull requests?

Comment: `git rm -rf database`, update index, commit

Comment: @hjpotter92, _**watch out!**_ Your command will also delete `database/` from the working copy. Make sure to use `--cached` if it should remain in the working copy, but be removed from git.

Comment: @Chris I will mark it as duplicate since solution is the same. I would like to ask you just if I add folder to .gitignore with these commands, will it be ignored no matter of branch on which I am working/committing?

Comment: @ldragicevic, maybe. Assuming your `.gitignore` is tracked by Git (it probably should be), it will probably change when you switch branches. It's a file, just like any other file. If it isn't tracked, and assuming there aren't any conflicts (e.g. by a `.gitignore` existing in another branch), it should take effect on all branches.